# PowerBI totals change based on chart type

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've run into an interesting issue today with a dashboard I am making.
I have 2 nearly identical measures that look like this:

```
DK_TCO_PerUser_UsageType = 
DIVIDE(
    [DK_TCO_AmountTotal],
    CALCULATE(
        [DK_BA_usercount],
        ALL(DK_UPC[Usage Type])
    )
)
```

And

```
DK_TCO_PerUser_Category = 
DIVIDE(
    [DK_TCO_AmountTotal],
    CALCULATE(
        [DK_BA_usercount],
        ALL(DK_UPC[TCO Category])
    )
)
```

As you can see, both of them use the Measure DK_TCO_AmountTotal (a simple SUM of a column) and divide with DK_BA_usercount (a distinct count of user id's in the same table), and based on what I want to display in the legend of my graph, the usercount needs to be unfiltered for that legend. Both measures seem to do what i want, but interestingly, for the second one, when i change the chart type from Matrix to Bar Chart, the totals change. In the image, I have copy pasted the same matrix 3 times, and displayed it as either a matrix, a card or a stacked bar chart. Everything shows the value I'd expect, except for the stacked bar chart for the DK_TCO_PerUser_Category measure, which suddenly has different totals. I have double checked that there are no blank values in my table for the category column, and I have even tried inserting a slicer, and checking each category individually, where they all line up, but when i multi-select all 5 values, the total is off again. There are no filters on any of the visuals, aside from the Quarter one as seen. Any idea as to where the issue could lie would be appreciated.

https://i.ibb.co/P49b8c4/PowerBI.png

Answer (score 0):

If you add the values in the first matrix the total matches that of the chart. The Total in the matrix isn't a total of the values but instead based on the result of the calculation of the measure without the category context.

Comment: I see, but if i add the two measures as line points on the chart i'm getting the values DK_TCO_AmountTotal = 938359,14 and a User-count of 3488 which comes out to the 269,02 value. And if I change the graph from stacked + line to clustered + line, suddenly the total is correct.

Comment: Can you update the question with the expressions used for `DK_TCO_AmountTotal`, and `DK_BA_usercount`. Also add these two measures to your first matrix (TCO Category) and share what that looks like.